# Use props with forEach in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm desperately trying to use my props 'datas' with a foreach.

When I put my data in a "test" data, it works.

Example :

```
data() {
            return {
                postForm: this.$vform({}),
                test: [{"name":"Couleur yeux","id":3,"answer":null},{"name":"Hanches","id":6,"answer":"'Test'"}],
            }
        },

computed: {

    },

    methods: {
        createForm() {
            this.test.forEach((data) => {
                if (data.answer) {
                    this.$set(this.postForm, data.id, data.answer)
                }
            })
        }
    },
```

But if I use my props directly, it doesn't work. I have a message "this.datas.forEach is not a function".

But my props has exactly the same data and the same structure as my "test" data.

Don't work:

```
this.datas.forEach((data) => {
                    if (data.answer) {
                        this.$set(this.postForm, data.id, data.answer)
                    }
                })
```

I also tried to transform my props into data() but it doesn't work

```
data() {
                return {
                    postForm: this.$vform({}),
                    test: this.datas
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

> "this.datas.forEach is not a function"

This mean that `datas` is not an Array instance because `forEach` is method from array prototype.

Comment: But the data of my props is an array… as in my message (model test)

Comment: How you define props? Did you set type to Array: `props: { datas: { type: Array } }`?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `this.datas` does not exist. You never give this the state with the key `datas`.
It looks like you're trying to go through `this.test`, which is an array of objects. Is that right?

If that's the goal, you can do so:

```
data() {
            return {
                postForm: this.$vform({}),
                test: [{"name":"Couleur yeux","id":3,"answer":null},{"name":"Hanches","id":6,"answer":"'Test'"}],
            }
        },

    methods: {
        createForm() {
            let arrayOfAnswers = []
            this.test.forEach((data) => {
                if (data.answer) {
                    arrayOfAnswes.push(data.answer)
                }
            })
            this.arrayOfanswers = arrayOfAnswers
        }
    },
```